# How to get async call to return response to main thread, using okhttp?

Tags: java, android, json, asynchronous, okhttp

I'm trying to make a program for Android, and I'm using okhttp for json-calls.
I really want to return my response to the outside of the thread I'm creating. I need to create the thread for an async call otherwise I'll get a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Problem is that I can't seem to get my response string outside the "onResponse" method, even though my responseString is a global variable in the class. Since it's async, the thread won't run in time to get my value in the global variable before it returns. How can I make sure I get the response, before it returns my responseString value?

Here's my code:

```
public static String getUserProductCategoriesFromServer(Activity activity, final String UID, final String EXPIRY, final String CLIENT, final String ACCESSTOKEN)
{
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(JsonStorage.getJsonUserProductCategories())
                    .get()
                    .addHeader("access-token", ACCESSTOKEN)
                    .addHeader("client", CLIENT)
                    .addHeader("expiry", EXPIRY)
                    .addHeader("uid", UID)
                    .build();



            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
                {
                    try
                    {
                        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                        String json = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                        JSONArray jsonData = (JSONArray) jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_product_category_names");
                        responseString = jsonData.toString();
                        Log.v("TEST1", jsonData.toString()); //RETURNS JSON :D
                        Log.v("TEST2", responseString); //RETURNS JSON :D
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    Log.v("TEST3", responseString); //RETURNS "NULL" :(
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: you can return Call and enqueue the result to your ui component, also you can create helper function to serialize your json data or you can use gson

Comment: you can create more functions for the next tasks to be performed after response and call those methods in your onResponse method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common way to get results from asynchronous world to synchronous (thread-based) is to use [Futures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). Many libraries implement such an interface, e.g. Guava. Standard java has implementation named [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). It uses methods with different names and signatures, but an adapter can be easily implemented:

```
class CallbackFuture extends CompletableFuture<Response> implements Callback {
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
         super.complete(response);
    }
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e){
         super.completeExceptionally(e);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
CallbackFuture future = new CallbackFuture();
client.newCall(request).enqueue(future);
Response response = future.get();
```

Having the `Response`, you can extract `responseString` the same way as you did it in the your first variant.

Comment: Thank you! To elaborate if someone else runs into this problem: Since I'm supporting API 23, and CompletableFuture is available from API 24+, I used streamsupport-cfuture library which is a backport of this feature (I think it supports all the way down to API 16). Since I'm using this customized callback, I can run it on the main thread and I no longer get a NetworkOnMainThreadException as okhttp3 gave me when I used their implementation. Thank you for this!